# changing trigger - button for <a>: in toggle.class JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I found this snippet how to toggle visibility of the div: http://jsbin.com/obElaNe/1

---

I would like to use it, I just need to have the effect triggered on click of  tag, not the button. Could somebody advise me how to do it please?

Comment: what is the `tag` you've mentioned here?

Comment: please share your html where you want to have this effect

Comment: it should be as simple as changing the element to which the click handler is registered to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/qaruy/1/edit

the only thing I did, I changed HTML element and jQuery selector, otherwise didn't understand the question.

Comment: ahh.. I forgot to change the selector :-) Thanks a lot!